# How many moderated user testings can a researcher handle?

Tags: users, testing

I enjoy doing user testing as a moderator, i.e. usability testing, contextual inquiry, but it's also emotionally draining for me (I wonder why?) Currently I'm doing it only once in a while. Majority of my time is doing other non-customer facing researches. But I am considering increasing it. Or even doing this full time.

My question to my fellow user researcher is, if this is your main task, how many can you handle, say, per week, per month, without it being too exhausting for you?

Thanks,

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to UX

Comment: True it is not directly related to ux, but it is relevant to ux professionals in my opinion. Otherwise, where can we get feedback on topics like this? If I get no reply in a couple of days, that might indicate it's not relevant in this forum.

Comment: Maybe [Project Management](https://pm.stackexchange.com/), or [The Work Place](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), or [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its entirely on topic:  moderating is highly intense because if you are doing it properly you are watching users like a hawk - something interesting can happen in a fraction  of a second - and you have to be alert enough to spot it.

As to the number of sessions you can do: its difficult to give a number.

The other criteria which drives available time is building enough analysis time into the schedule so you have time to think about what is going on, so if there's a pattern emerging you can ask 'better questions' to later test subjects using what you've learnt from the earlier ones.

Comment: I highly agree with building analysis time in between sessions. About how much time to allocate, are we talking about hours? days? I scheduled my last study to be an hour apart. Two days back to back. It was a usability test. Felt like a day in between would probably be better. Thanks very much for your insight!

Comment: 2-3 hours : it depends how much data you are ending up collecting.   I've always found it useful to have some 'thinking time' where you've looked at the recordings again and done some basic analysis but then just put them down and think about what's going on (even if its just over lunch). Sort of 'zen' UX.